# Run python program remotely for large Machine Learning program

Tags: python, server

I have just gotten into machine learning and I have some big programs that I need to run. They take about 10 hours, but currently I only have a MacBook Pro to run them on. I travel around a lot and therefore can't leave my programs running during the day. I am a bit unfamiliar with servers, can someone point me in the direction to some resources or provide some information to where I can run a python program remotely and the infrastructure that I need to do so?

Comment: One solution might be to find a cheap desktop PC somewhere (a cheap second-hand PC might be just as fast as your MacBook Pro), and leave it at home. You could then install Linux and set up ssh access. This would be an afternoon project if you've never set up ssh before. Another solution could be a dedicated HPC service like Sabalcore.

Comment: Say I have a mac mini, do I need to install Linux on it for SSH access or are there any good SSH tools for OSX?

Comment: OSX comes with ssh support (client and server), so you don't need Linux. You want to be careful when you set up ssh since you'll be making it accessible to the public internet. I'm not familiar with the steps to do this on a Mac, but the most important things are to use an authentication key rather than a password (and disable password-login for ssh), and make sure only that one user account is set up for ssh access. There are lots of webpages on the internet that explain the steps on Linux. They should be very similar on a Mac as well.

Comment: Also, another option is that the Mac has a "Remote Login" feature that enables ssh: osxdaily.com/2011/09/30/remote-login-ssh-server-mac-os-x. I cannot comment on the security of this method, so that would be something to look into or possibly ask on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Subscribe to AWS
- create one virtual server (using EC2 service), possibly Linux instance, e.g. Amazon default one
- manage to log into that virtual server
- install byobu (console, which can run in background)
- install your python program there
- use byobu console to start the code and close the byobu without closing the session.

Later on

- log into the virtual server
- start byobu
- see the results.

If you really need to run the services longer time, you can later install supervisord and configure the program to run under it. It will allow you to start/stop/restart and see logs created by the program.

One advantage with AWS is, you can stop the server when not needed and you pay only for the hours you use it. Other providers of virtual servers may provide similar service (I use sometime Digital Ocean, but there are many more).

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for a cloud based virtual machine. Personally I have used AWS to spin up virtual instances a number of times. Once the server is running all you need to do is get your files to the VM and then run them from terminal in the same way you would from your Mac.

I would recommend that you choose a Ubuntu Server AMI as your starting place because commands from the terminal will be more familiar to you than another distribution. As a side benefit, python is already installed on Ubuntu so thats one less thing you have to do.

VMs are quite inexpensive to run (as long as you don't go crazy). There are many complicated ways to run a script remotely, but I myself am a fan of simple solutions unless a more complicated one is warranted. Simple FTP your files to the server and the SSH in for remote access.

Once you setup a vm the steps might look like this:

```
sftp username@publicdns.amazon.com
cd /appropriateFolder/
put *.py
bye
ssh username@publicdns.amazon.com
cd /appropriateFolder/
python myScript.py > output.log &
```

The last line will run your python script in the background and dump anything you print to a file. Look at amazon's pricing list and you can easily find a VM that matches or beats the specs of your MBP. Using a cloud instance has the added benefit of being able to shut it down and stop paying for it when you're done running your scripts.

Good luck!